# spark write as string and read partition column as numeric

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parquet, partition

I found my business code have some illegal data, after debug ,I find this bug is caused by spark partitions resolve, what should I do to avoid this problem without change write partition columns.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(("122D", 2), ("122F", 2), ("122", 2))
      .toDF("no", "value")
      .withColumn("other", lit(1))

val path = "/user/my/output"

df
  .write
  .partitionBy("no","value")
  .parquet(path)
```

**my expected result is read as aame as write**

```
df.show()
+----+-----+-----+
|  no|value|other|
+----+-----+-----+
|122D|    2|    1|
|122F|    2|    1|
| 122|    2|    1|
+----+-----+-----+

// df.distinct.count==3
```

**actual read result like this**

```
val read=spark.read.parquet(path)

read.show()
+-----+-----+-----+
|other|   no|value|
+-----+-----+-----+
|    1|122.0|    2|
|    1|122.0|    2|
|    1|122.0|    2|
+-----+-----+-----+

// read.distinct.count==1
```

check the `output` dir structure is this

```
└─output
    ├─no=122
    │  └─value=2
    ├─no=122D
    │  └─value=2
    └─no=122F
        └─value=2
```

Thanks a lot.
my spark version is `2.4.5` and scala version is `2.11.12`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just add `spark.conf.set("spark.sql.sources.partitionColumnTypeInference.enabled",false)`

Answer (score 0):

**For theoretical knowledge** : All built-in file sources (including Text/CSV/JSON/ORC/Parquet) are able to discover and infer partitioning information automatically. Data types of the partitioning columns are automatically inferred.

**You can use** : `spark.sql.sources.partitionColumnTypeInference.enabled` as False.

**Make Sure That** : When type inference is disabled, string type will be used for the partitioning columns.